# LINQ .ToListAsync failing when using two tables

Tags: c#, linq

MY function works fine when not running asynchronous but when I try to change it over to `.ToListAsync()` it fails with

> "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be
>   used for operations that require a connection"

The following is what fails...

```
public async void UpdateNoAction()
{
    await (from r in Context.CodingReview
       from s in Context.UserDetails.Where(s => s.reviewId = r.id)
       where ...
       select new ExtendedDetails(){
           Review = r,
           Spell = s
       }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Context is an entity framework db connection. The return type is void so I actually get the error message as opposed to failing silently but will be changed to a bool later on.

If I remove the `Context.UserDetails` section for testing purposes it works fine. Any ideas as to why it would be failing?

Comment: show us your full method.

Comment: What is the Context in your case? It seems like it is a database connection and you are closing/disposing it before the async method is completed.

Comment: What is the life-cycle of `Context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the problem is related with `async void` usage.
I guess you are opening a connection in some other method and calling this method inside that one and closing the connection. `async void` type methods are fire and forget types, which means that before execution is complete method returns; then your db connection may be closed before this method completes its operation.

update the method signiture from `public async void UpdateNoAction()` to `public async Task UpdateNoAction()` or to `public async Task<List<ExtendedDetails>> UpdateNoAction()`; then I guess the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Changing the type does stop the error message appearing but then the query just fails silently.

Comment: can you just debug and check the function returns properly without async keyword (remove async keyword and change ToListAsync with ToList)?

Comment: Hold up, you're bang on point, I'd not made the parent function async and it was also of return type void. Changed that over and it works fine again. Thanks :)